# Convert Word file (doc/docx) in to html text

Tags: c#, html, ms-word

I don't want to use Interop objects as Excel wis not installed in my computer.
If separate dll is there for Interop than its OK.

Comment: If it's an OOXML file (docx) then you can use the OOXML SDK to get at the raw XML of the document and piece together the content from that. For pre-2007 *.doc files you're stuck as they're in a proprietary binary format.

Comment: see discussion here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161791/word-97-2003-document-to-html-conversion-programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [OpenXml PowerTools](https://powertools.codeplex.com/). [Here is the documentation](http://openxmldeveloper.org/wiki/w/wiki/powertools-for-open-xml.aspx).

And [here is the doc/video](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2014/01/30/transform-docx-to-html-css-with-high-fidelity-using-powertools-for-open-xml.aspx) how you use Html conversion.

Unfortunately this only works for DOCX.
DOC is a different format and OpenXML tools won't work on it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
I tried with this OpenXML power tool & its worked.

I need to work for .doc file also. So if you have any solution for .doc file than please reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DocX](http://docx.codeplex.com/), it has a nice api and you don't need to use the interop libs.

Comment: Is it a free library?
If you can provide a sample code than it will be a great help.

Comment: I recommend you to check out their examples, here's one: http://cathalscorner.blogspot.co.il/2010/12/replace-text-across-many-documents-in.html

Comment: I didn't got any code to Get HTML from word file into that.
I searched options too. But don't have any solution to convert doc to HTML.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I thought there is an html string inside a doc/docx file and you want to extract it. What I understand now is that you want to get a the doc/docx formatted as html and keep the same look? If so, please update your question to be more specific and clear.